# How to reopen question?

Tags: support

This is w.r.t this question [Depression of freezing point](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104201/depression-of-freezing-point)
And this [Reason for shorter bond between sulphur and oxygen?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/107934/reason-for-shorter-bond-between-sulphur-and-oxygen)

I have tried my best to re edit the question , I have also asked for reason why it’s unclear I didn’t receive any response

Also for future reference please provide necessary action to be taken place to deal with similar situation

Comment: See also: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: I tried commenting and flagging on the question I didnt get any reply